# How to access a parametric object property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Object #1:

```
var chosenProperties = { 'size' : 'large' }
```

`chosenProperties` are properties that user wants to access from the below object. This object is created based on a form values.

Object #2:

```
var allProperties = { 'sizes' : { 'large' : 'x', 'small' : 'y' } }
```

Normally I would write `allProperties.sizes.large` to have `x` displayed but what if I need to access `x` if I only have `chosenProperties`? I'm sure that there is some method to do that but nothing comes to my mind.

Comment: not clear what you mean/want? Do you not have `allProperties` available? Do you have it, but want to access a dynamic value based on `chosenProperties` selection?

Comment: "Do you have it, but want to access a dynamic value based on chosenProperties selection?" - that's right.

Comment: yup, Bruno's answer should do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everytime the name of the property is contained in a different variable,  you can use square brackets notation to access that property.

```
allProperties.sizes[chosenProperties.size]
```

**UPDATE**

Since ES2015 it's possible to use square brackets also inside an object literal.

```
var field = "foo";

const obj = {
  [field]: "bar"
};

obj.foo; // bar
```

Answer (score 1):

not 100% sure what you are trying to do here but you know you can:

```
allProperties.sizes[chosenProperies.size]
```

Should return X

Answer (score 1):

allProperties.sizes[chosenProperties.size]

Answer (score 1):

```
if (chosenProperties.size) {
    allProperties.sizes[chosenProperties.size]
}
```